# Why does using a blank/empty volume in docker-compose.yml allow persistence but using a relative path fails (eg jenkins gui unavailable)?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, yaml, docker-run

### Questions:

1. Why does a relative host volume path (i.e., `./jenkins_home:...`) prevent jenkins from serving it's GUI yet an empty volume path allows jenkins to serve it's GUI?
2. Where is the aliased host volume (i.e., `volumes: jenkins_home: <no value>`) stored on the host?

### Context:

This situation is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57040274/7490713 but I'm unsure why the solution works.

Using Docker Desktop `docker-compose` on Windows 10, with a relative path (i.e., `./jenkins_home:...`) for the host volume location correctly persists data to the current directory, & port 50000 is accessible, however, port 8080 (i.e., Jenkins GUI) is unavailable:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  jenkins:
    image: 'jenkins/jenkins:lts'
    restart: 'unless-stopped'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '50000:50000'
    volumes:
      - './jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home' # Relative path (jenkins GUI doesn't work).

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
```

```sh
ping http://localhost:50000 # Success.
ping http://localhost:8080 # Not found.
```

Whereas using an empty host volume path works:

```yaml
# ...
services:
  jenkins:
    # ...
    volumes:
      - 'jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home' # Aliased empty path (jenkins GUI works).

volumes:
  # NOTE: Empty path value used below.
  jenkins_home:
```

```sh
ping http://localhost:8080 # Success.
```

For comparison, the jenkins GUI is accessible when using `docker run` with a host volume path alias as below (although I'm unsure where this is located on the host machine):
Running jenkins via `docker run` successfully makes the jenkins GUI available:

```sh
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

The relative volume path makes the jenkins GUI inaccessible, it seems this is because persistence doesn't work in this situation, which prevents jenkins from serving it's GUI on `http://localhost:8080`, & somehow using an empty volume path via volume alias allows persistence & the GUI to be served - the question is why does the relative path cause the GUI to not serve yet the empty path causes the GUI to serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the GUI not being available is an application-specific issue this can not be answered solely from a `docker` perspective. But most probably the cause here is the difference between [`volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and [`bind-mounts`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) in `docker`, namely in the way these are initialized on creation:

While for `bind-mounts` simply the specified directory on the host will be mounted into the container as-is, new `volumes` are created by `docker` if they don't exist yet and [populated with the contents of the target directory from the image](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container). This includes also setting the same permissions for the `volume`.

So for your question 1.: look for error messages in the container's log regarding `permission denied` / `access denied` or missing files/directories in `/var/jenkins_home`. If so you just need to set the correct permissions for `./jenkins_home` or initialize the expected contents manually (how exactly is an application-specific issue).

Regarding question 2.: [where the contents of the volumes are stored on disk is managed by `docker`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and dependent on the configuration of the `docker` daemon and host. Normally *you should not need to care about this* and only manage them via the [`docker volume` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_ls/).

See [the `docker` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) for more on this.

Comment: Regarding question 1, I didn't find any permission errors in the container's log, however, your point on volumes & bind-mounts makes sense since the relative path would cause OS dependencies hence permission issues, which would cause the GUI to fail. Regarding question 2, I was curious on the location but thanks for the resources. I'm marking this as accepted as I found your answers & explanation useful in answering the questions :)